# How can I delete an AWS Elemental MediaLive reservation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-billing, aws-media-live, aws-elemental, aws-mediaservices

I have been using and testing some features of AWS MediaLive, and last week I added two offerings to my offering cart and purchased them. However, I have discovered that I have been charged more than I anticipated, and I would like to delete this reservation now.

Unfortunately, I am unable to find the 'delete' button as described in the guide [1], and I suspect that this may be because the reservation contract has not yet expired.

Is there any way to terminate this contract early, and will I continue to be charged even if I don't use it?

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/medialive/latest/ug/deleting-reservations.html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1YJl.png)

=======

1. When attempting to delete using the web console: there is no [Delete] button.
2. When attempting to delete using Cloud9, I used the following AWS CLI command:
   *$ aws medialive delete-reservation --reservation-id ***** --output json*

and the result:
*An error occurred (ConflictException) when calling the DeleteReservation operation: Cannot delete an active reservation*

Answer (score 1):

Reservation is a contract with AWS and so you cannot simply cancel or delete the active reservation. You should contact to AWS Support and discuss with them, request to cancel the reservation.